Why is my console not immediately printing the previous line when using a java scanner?
I have the following simple Java program, which asks for a username (via the Scanner) and a password (via the Console). Note I am NOT running this in an IDE such as eclipse, so that bug does not apply to my situation (in particular I'm running this on powershell). We may always assume a console exists.
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Console console = System.console();
        
        System.out.print("User: ");
        String user = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\r\n");
        System.out.println("User entered was: " + user); //POINT 1
        

        
        String password = new String(console.readPassword("Enter password: "));
        System.out.println("\r\n");
        System.out.println("Password entered: " + password); //POINT 2
    }
}

Here is what I tried/what was expected:
When I run the program it prompts me with
[User: ]
as expected. However, when I press ENTER on my keyboard, it takes the cursor to the beginning of the line and does NOT proceed to "POINT 1". When I press enter again, we proceed to "POINT 1" and display the user as expected.

UPON RUNNING PROGRAM the console looks like this:
[PS C:\..\Password] > java -cp "myBin" Main
User: foo|[<---BLINKING CURSOR]


PRESSING ENTER once (UNEXPECTED behavior!!)
[PS C:\..\Password] > java -cp "myBin" Main
|[<---BLINKING CURSOR]User: foo


PRESSING ENTER a second time (expected behavior)
[PS C:\..\Password] > java -cp "myBin" Main
User: foo

User entered was: foo
Enter password: |[<---BLINKING CURSOR]


Password 'bar' entered and PRESSING ENTER a third time (expected behavior)
[PS C:\..\Password] > java -cp "myBin" Main
User: foo

User entered was: foo
Enter password: <non-echoed characters 'bar'>


Password entered: bar
[PS C:\..\Password] > |[<---BLINKING CURSOR] #program ended at "POINT 2".

EDIT: After trying this is CMD (windows 11), it seems that the problem is powershell... Anyone have a workaround?

You shouldn't be using both Scanner and Console at the same time

I was guessing someone would say this. Unfortunately, the issue is that the Scanner is widely used in a legacy (command line) application I'm working on...
And I need a way to allow the user to enter passwords without echoing them... and the scanner doesn't allow for that.

I'll be surprised if that's going to happen where they play nicely with each other, as they'll both be using stdin at the same time. But actually I don't get your point: if you have the source of the legacy app (in order to use Console) then why don't you change it to using Console for passwords?

What do you mean by your question?
Currently the legacy program uses the scanner, NOT console. Hence, whenever the user types sensitive info, it is echoed back to them, which is undesirable. (I.e. it seems that to fix this one problem of reading passwords, we'd have to refactor ALL calls to scanner to be calls to console).

Where passwords are involved, yes. What's more, Console is the 'correct' class to use, as Scanner is really specialized for tokenization, not console input

BTW I cannot reproduce the problem using OpenJDK 23 or Oracle Java 1.8.0_202 (but I agree that you should use only one and not both input sources)

( tested using cmd.exe and PowerShell, not reproduced )

Java's System.out is buffered, meaning that output isn't necessarily displayed immediately. When you use System.out.print, the output may remain in the buffer until:

The buffer is flushed (manually or automatically)
A newline \n or System.out.println is printed
The program terminates.

This can lead to a situation where the program appears to pause while waiting for input.
You can use System.out.flush() before scanner.nextInt(); to ensure that the output is immediately written to the console. another alternative is to use System.out.println Instead of System.out.print example :
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
int number = scanner.nextInt();

